# Why is Javascript contained in a string variable executing as soon as it is assigned to another string variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

This one will require some setup for you to understand what I am trying to do.  It involves both templating and asynchronous calls.  I am aware of the intricacies and nuances of async calls.

I have a piece of javascript, in a .js file.  The script contains some "tags" that need to be replaced with actual variables, which are different on each use.  You will notice the "`{{tags}}`" embedded in the script.  You will also notice that the script contains an ajax call to a C# Generic Handler. :

```
// this is template code from LoadFlights.js, called from LoadFlights() in main.js...
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "js/handlers/LoadFlights.ashx",
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,

    data: {
        DateStart: "{{DATESTART}}",
        DateEnd: "{{DATEEND}}",
        Specific: JSON.stringify({DAY: "{{DAY}}", DEP: "{{DEP}}", CARRIER: "{{CARRIER}}", FLT: "{{FLT}}", LEGCD: "{{LEGCD}}"})
    },

    success: function (result) {
        callback_LoadFlights(result);
    },

    error: function (result) {
        alert(result.responseText);
        return false;
    }
});

function callback_LoadFlights(result) {
    alert(result);
}
// end
```

I get the script with a jquery `.get()` call, and in the `.done()` callback, I attempt to assign the retrieved script code to a variable.

```
function runScript(source, parameters) {

    if (URLExists(source)) {

        var getScript = $.get({
            url: source,
            dataType: "script"
        })
            .done(function (scriptCode) {

                var code = scriptCode;

                // replace any passed parameters...
                for (var p in parameters) {
                    code = code.replace("{{" + p + "}}", parameters[p]);
                }

                // remove any unused parameter placeholders...

                while (code.indexOf("{{") >= 0) {
                    code = code.substr(0, code.indexOf("{{")) + code.substr(code.indexOf("}}") + 2);
                }

                var s = document.createElement('script');

                s.type = "text/javascript";
                s.text = code;

                document.body.appendChild(s);

            })

            .fail(function () {
                alert("Failed to retrieve script: " + source);
            })

    }
```

(I omitted the `else` for brevity sake.)

What happens is that on this line:

```
var code = scriptCode;
```

The code immediately executes, and the Generic Handler call fires, and immediately fails with "invalid date format" (the first line that attempts to use DateStart) because DateStart still equals "{{DATESTART}}".  **None of the code that replaces the tags executes.**

Even if I set a breakpoint on that line and attempt to step **INTO** it to see what might be happening, it still immediately fires the generic handler call.

In the debugger, I `typeof`'d both code and scriptCode in the Immediate Window, and both return "string".

I'm tempted to believe that a JavaScript error of some sort is occurring, immediately killing the JavaScript code block and stopping it's execution.

But HOW is the Generic Handler being fired then?  By all appearances, it seems as though the javascript retrieved by the `.get().done()` is being executed by simply assigning it to another variable. Is this even possible? Can anyone see what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for `jQuery.ajax()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

When the `dataType` is `script`:

> "script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text.

So jQuery is evaluating your javascript before you've had a chance to parse it. *Then* it gives you the text of the script, but by this point it's too late. Try changing the datatype to 'text' then parse it.

Comment: I am assuming the option exists for the get() like it does for ajax().  If this fixes the problem, I will have just one more question.  Where do I ship your case of beer?  ;-)

Comment: Your eagle eye saved the day, @Mark_M.  Thank you very much!